# Update recycler View on a Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know there is other questions like this with answers but they don't help me...

So I have a Fragment, in this one I use Volley to get a JSON from a Web API. What I want to do is to "refresh" my recycler view with the data I get in my response.

I have tried to add a method in my adapter. But nothing append when I try to change my adapter in my Volley.onresponse() method.

There is my Fragment :

```
public class TicketsIncidentsFragment extends Fragment implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<String> {

    RequestQueue queue;
    StringRequest stringRequest;
    ListView listView;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    String url;

    private TicketsIncidentsViewModel ticketsIncidentsViewModel;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ticketsIncidentsViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TicketsIncidentsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticketsincidents, container, false);



        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        MyAdapterTI myAdapterTI=new MyAdapterTI();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapterTI);



        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        url = "http://myip/select/ticketsI";

        stringRequest = new StringRequest(GET, url, TicketsIncidentsFragment.this, TicketsIncidentsFragment.this);

        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


        Gson gsonTicketsIncidents = new Gson();

        ResponseJson responseJson = new ResponseJson();

        responseJson = (ResponseJson) gsonTicketsIncidents.fromJson(response, ResponseJson.class);

        List<Object> listTicketsIncidents = responseJson.getResponse();
        try {
            JSONArray tis = new JSONArray(listTicketsIncidents.toArray());
            ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> nomUser = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0 ; i< tis.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject ticketIncident = tis.getJSONObject(i);

                nomUser.add(ticketIncident.get("NOMUSER").toString());
                date.add(ticketIncident.get("DateSAISIE").toString());

            }


            MyAdapterTI myAdapterTI=new MyAdapterTI();

            myAdapterTI.getList(nomUser, date);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapterTI);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

There is my adapter :

```
public class MyAdapterTI extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterTI.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Pair<String, String>> TI;

    public void getList(ArrayList<String> nomUser, ArrayList<String> date){

        for(int i =0; i<nomUser.size();i++){
            TI = Arrays.asList( Pair.create(nomUser.get(i), date.get(i)));
        }

    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapterTI.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cell_ti, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapterTI.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pair<String, String> pair = TI.get(position);
        holder.display(pair);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private  TextView nomUser;
        private  TextView date;

        private Pair<String, String> currentPair;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nomUser=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomuser);
            date=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }

        public void display(Pair<String, String> pair) {
            currentPair=pair;
            nomUser.setText(pair.first);
            date.setText(pair.second);

        }
    }
}
```

And there is the layout :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_TI"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.917"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />



        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="680dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.039" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank's for you're help

---

UPDATE :

Now my MyAdapter.getList() looks like this :

```
public void getList(ArrayList<String> nomUser, ArrayList<String> date){


        for(int i =1; i<nomUser.size();i++){

            TI.add(Pair.create(nomUser.get(i), date.get(i)));


        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But nothing change yet.

---

Last UPDATE :

The problem has been solved.

It's a ridiculous mistake I've made in my Adapter.

I used to return 0 but the solution is this :

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TI.size();
    }
```

Comment: try adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you set data to adapter

Comment: are you sure onResponse is called? have u try debug it?

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig I tried too but nothing happend...

Comment: @RofieSagara Yes it's called

Comment: change TI = Arrays.asList( Pair.create(nomUser.get(i), date.get(i))); to Ti.add(Pair.create(nomUser.get(i), date.get(i))

Comment: on Response try to clear your list first and then add the new list again to the adapter and then call notifyDataset changed

Comment: private List<Pair<String, String>> TI = new ArrayList(); and this too

Comment: @RofieSagara yes i was thinking about this at the beginning but there is no Pair.add ...

Comment: not Pair.add() but IT.add()

Comment: @RajatBeck I understand, can you help me about how do I clear my list ? It's the first time I use RecyclerView...

Comment: There are a couple of things that you are doing it wrong return ```TI.size()``` in your ```getItemCount``` function, and inside your getList function first call ```TI.clear()``` and then prepare a new list and then do ```notifyDataSetChanged```.

Comment: @RajatBeck OH, I think it's on a good way, know this is working, I just have a huge space between items, but I will work for this. Tahnk's a lot

Comment: @NeoKerd upvote please it the comment helped you.

Comment: @RajatBeck It's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
@Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
```

to

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      if(TI == null)
        return 0;
      else 
       return TI.size;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    MyAdapterTI myAdapterTI=new MyAdapterTI(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ThisIsYourList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapterTI);
```

Don't do this in response

```
    MyAdapterTI myAdapterTI=new MyAdapterTI();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapterTI);
```

`myAdapterTI` make this global variable

Only update your list and then

```
myAdapterTI.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or in your adapter, you can do

```
this.notifyDataSetChanged(); ////in getList
```

Comment: first, you can try this in the adapter

this.notifyDataSetChanged(); ////in getList

Comment: this problem will solve after doing this
if not then tell me

Comment: yes I tried, I put the change in my question at the end with the "UPDATE" section

Comment: you used this.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Ahmad I put the this.notifyDataSetChanged() in the getList method. Where do I use the clear ?

Comment: You can clear previous list in getList(....) function in adapter
in getList() function you can do
TI.clear

Comment: Ok now I do, but nothing happend, I have debug step by step and everything is doing well, but I can't find why the recyclerView never show up

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<Pair<String, String>> TI = new ArrayList();

public void getList(ArrayList<String> nomUser, ArrayList<String> date){

    for(int i =0; i<nomUser.size();i++){
        TI.add(Pair.create(nomUser.get(i), date.get(i)));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```